# New to Ansible & looking for correct filter syntax

Tags: filter, scripting, ansible

Here is my playbook

```
  tasks:
  - name: Load Variables
    include_vars: vars2.yml
    
  - name: show system info
    panos_op:
      provider: '{{ provider }}'
      cmd: '<show><system><info/></system></show>'
      cmd_is_xml: true
    register: systeminfo
  
  - debug: 
      msg: '{{systeminfo.stdout}}'
```

THE OUTPUT IS:

```
                "app-release-date": null,
                "app-version": "8103-5197",
                "av-release-date": null,
                "av-version": "0",
                "cloud-mode": "non-cloud",
                "default-gateway": "192.168.55.2",
                "devicename": "PA-VM-Firewall",
                "family": "vm",
                "global-protect-client-package-version": "0.0.0",
                "global-protect-clientless-vpn-release-date": null,
                "global-protect-clientless-vpn-version": "0",
                "global-protect-datafile-release-date": "unknown",
                "global-protect-datafile-version": "unknown",
                "hostname": "PA-VM-Firewall",
                "ip-address": "192.168.55.200",
                "ipv6-address": "unknown",
                "ipv6-default-gateway": null,
                "ipv6-link-local-address": "fe80::20c:29ff:fef0:5639/64",
                "is-dhcp": "no",
                "logdb-version": "9.0.10",
                "mac-address": "00:0c:29:f0:56:39",
                "model": "PA-VM",
                "multi-vsys": "off",
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                "operational-mode": "normal",
                "platform-family": "vm",
                "plugin_versions": {
                    "entry": {
                        "@name": "vm_series",
                        "@version": "1.0.2",
                        "pkginfo": "vm_series-1.0.2"
                    }
                },
                "public-ip-address": "unknown",
                "serial": "0153510123456",
                "sw-version": "9.0.1",
                "threat-release-date": null,
                "threat-version": "0",
                "time": "Tue Oct  6 22:03:33 2020",
                "uptime": "0 days, 0:29:00",
                "url-db": "paloaltonetworks",
                "url-filtering-version": "20201007.20031",
                "vm-cpuid": "ESX:E9060900FFFB8B1F",
                "vm-license": "VM-50",
                "vm-mac-base": "7C:89:C1:B1:C4:00",
                "vm-mac-count": "256",
                "vm-mode": "VMWare ESXi",
                "vm-uuid": "564D7A26-6146-CD3F-26CF-302C49F05639",
                "vpn-disable-mode": "off",
                "wf-private-release-date": "unknown",
                "wf-private-version": "0",
                "wildfire-release-date": null,
                "wildfire-version": "0"
```

What is the syntax to print out only things I need (Ex: I need to print only hostname, serial, sw-version,ip-address)

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what type is `systeminfo.stdout`. If it is a `dict` you can directly access it as: `systeminfo.stdout.hostname` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://ansible-pan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/panos_op_module.html), `panps_op` produces valid `json`. What you posted is not, but I assume, you just didn't post all of it.
You can parse the `json` output and then access it as a dict:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Load Variables
    include_vars: vars2.yml
    
  - name: show system info
    panos_op:
      provider: '{{ provider }}'
      cmd: '<show><system><info/></system></show>'
      cmd_is_xml: true
    register: tmp  

  - name: parse json
    set_fact:
      sysinfo: "{{ tmp.stdout | from_json }}"

  - name: print relevant information
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ sysinfo['system'][item] }}"
    loop:
      - hostname
      - serial
      - sw-version
      - ip-address
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Yes, i did not include full output bcz "panos_op" module will give me the same output in two formats JSON (stdout) & XML (stdout_xml). So I mentioned stdout in debug just to get output in JSON format.

I tried your code and resulted me in error below, please advise.

fatal: [192.168.55.200]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ tmp | from_json }}): the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict"}

Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot the `stdout`. Fixed it in my answer.

Comment: No, here is the error "atal: [192.168.11.200]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'system'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/test/Downloads/lab/test.yml': line 23, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: print relevant information\n    ^ here\n"}"

Comment: I don't have a system to test this, so I was going by the docs. The output should look like this: `{system: {app-release-date: ...`. I don't have your output, but you might adapt `msg: "{{ sysinfo['system'][item] }}"` to fix this. Or you can show me the first lines of the output, as they are not in your question.